# creating an intent within a button onclickhandler

Tags: android

```
  btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
            {

                public void onClick(View v) {

                     Intent i = new Intent(this,DetailEventActivity.class);


                     // Create the view using FirstGroup's LocalActivityManager
                     View view = FeaturedTabGroup.group.getLocalActivityManager()
                     .startActivity("show_city", i
                     .addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP))
                     .getDecorView();

                     // Again, replace the view
                     FeaturedTabGroup.group.replaceView(view);

                }

            });
```

http://web.archive.org/web/20100816175634/http://blog.henriklarsentoft.com/2010/07/android-tabactivity-nested-activities/

I'm following this tutorial that switches activities within a tabhost tab, but for some reason my  `Intent i = new Intent(this,DetailEventActivity.class);` is throwing an error.
If I add the code in my onCreate it works, but I want to execute on a click.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**See the example code below and edit it according to your usage**,

```
Button btnLoad = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.btnLoad);
            btnLoad.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                            NewCalling.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    dialog.cancel();
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Intent i = new Intent(this,DetailEventActivity.class);
```

In this line of code, `this` refers to a OnClickListener, and not a context. Should be `YourActivity.this`